# bootstrap navbar sticks to top by default in safari browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari, navbar

I set the navbar of my site to only stick to the top when you scroll. But it stays at the top by default on safari. Here is my site: [krishagric.com](http://krishagric.com)

[safari browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC84d.jpg)

How do i fix it to work like other browsers.
Here is the navbar html and css code:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  margin: none;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 5px; /* When the element reaches top: 5px, it becomes fixed. */
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top sticky" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="consultation.html">Consultation</a></li>
              <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari needs a little extra love here (name prefixing). So to `.sticky` add:

`position: -webkit-sticky;`